# Initialize Geoexplorer with layers

Tags: layers, geoexplorer

I have Geoexplorer war file deployed in Tomcat 7 webapps folder and I run it from localhost:8080/geoexplorer and load the layers and I visualize them correctly but when I close the browser and open Geoexplorer again I have to reload all the layers. How can I do to open Geoexplorer with the layers loaded?